# What does a "hard stand departure" mean?

Tags: terminology

I am reading a table explaining how to plan multiple diversion returns from an individual station:

> - widebody gate departures - xx minutes
> - narrow body gate departures - xx minutes
> - all hard stand departures - xx minutes

I am not a native English speaker and do not understand what a "hard stand departure" is.

Could anybody please explain this term?

Comment: A departure originate from hard stand instead of jet bridge at terminal?

Answer (score 16):

A hardstand is a type of parking spot separate from the terminal.  Wide/narrow body gates are associated with the connection to the terminal, where a hardstand is just an area of pavement reinforced for heavy vehicles (or airplanes).